# Plot cnn intermediate layer in keras subclass model

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I have the following subclass model:

```py
class MyModel(tf.keras.Model):

    def __init__(self, dropout_ratio=0.25, activation='relu', *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.layer_list = []
        # Input = 256
        self.layer_list.append(
            Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='valid', name='cnn_256pix_1', activation=activation, strides=1, dtype='float32'))
        self.layer_list.append(
            Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='valid', name='cnn_256pix_2', activation=activation, strides=1))

        self.layer_list.append(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
        self.layer_list.append(Dropout(dropout_ratio))
        # 128
        self.layer_list.append(
            Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='valid', name='cnn_128pix_1', activation=activation, strides=1))
        self.layer_list.append(
            Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='valid', name='cnn_128pix_2', activation=activation, strides=1))

        self.layer_list.append(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
        self.layer_list.append(Dropout(dropout_ratio))
        # 64
        self.layer_list.append(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding='valid', name='cnn_64pix_1', activation=activation))
        self.layer_list.append(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding='valid', name='cnn_64pix_2', activation=activation))
        self.layer_list.append(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
        self.layer_list.append(Dropout(dropout_ratio))

        self.layer_list.append(Flatten())
        self.layer_list.append(Dense(1024, activation=activation))
        self.layer_list.append(Dropout(0.3))
        self.layer_list.append(Dense(1024, activation=activation))
        self.layer_list.append(Dropout(0.3))
        self.layer_list.append(Dense(19, activation="softmax"))

    def call(self, inputs, **kwargs):
        print("shape: ", tf.shape(inputs))
        inp = inputs
        for layer in self.layer_list:
            inp = layer(inp)  # inp = tensor (1, 256, 256, 3) dtype=float32

        out = {self.layer_list[-1].name: self.layer_list[-1]}
        return out

    def compile(self, loss='mse', optimizer=RMSprop(lr=0.0001, clipvalue=1.0), **kwargs):
        self.output_names = self.layer_list[-1].name
        return super().compile(loss=loss, optimizer=optimizer, **kwargs)
```

and the code for plotting the cnn intermediate layer is this:

```py
model = MyModel()
print(evaluation_img.shape)  # (1, 256, 256, 3)
model.build(evaluation_img.shape)  # or equally (I think) model(evaluation_img)

layer_to_print = []
    for layer in model.layer_list:
        if "cnn" in layer.name:
            layer_to_print.append(layer)

input = tf.keras.Input(shape=evaluation_img.shape)  # shape=(None, 1, 256, 256, 3), dtype=float32)
for el in layer_to_print:
    intermediate_layer_model = Model(inputs=input, outputs=el(input))
    intermediate_output = intermediate_layer_model.predict(evaluation_img)
    plt.matshow(intermediate_output[0, :, :, intermediate_output.shape[3]-1], cmap='viridis')
    plt.show()
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer cnn_256pix_2 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 32 but received input with shape [None, 1, 256, 256, 3]
```

and this warning:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 1, 256, 256, 3) for input Tensor("input_1:0", shape=(None, 1, 256, 256, 3), dtype=float32), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None, 256, 256, 3).
```

The idea is to plot what is output from the layers of the various cnn. The code above works fine with `Sequential()` models, but not with this subclass model. I can only plot the first intermediate_layer (first cnn layer).

Does anyone have any idea how I can fix the error?

Answer (score 0):

**Sample working code**

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
input_shape = (1, 256, 256, 3)
x = tf.random.normal(input_shape)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape[1:]))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape[1:]))

output = model(x)
```